# Problems installing node and npm

Tags: node.js, homebrew

I am trying to run the command

1. `brew install node`

and getting the warning:

```
node 12.12.0 is already installed, it's just not linked
You can use `brew link node` to link this version.
```

2. When running `brew link node`, I get the error

```
Error: Could not symlink include/node/common.gypi
Target /usr/local/include/node/common.gypi
already exists. You may want to remove it:
  rm '/usr/local/include/node/common.gypi'

To force the link and overwrite all conflicting files:
  brew link --overwrite node

To list all files that would be deleted:
  brew link --overwrite --dry-run node
```

3. Next, I ran `rm '/usr/local/include/node/common.gypi'`
   and it asks

```
override rw-r--r--  root/wheel for /usr/local/include/node/common.gypi?
```

4. When typing y

it says

```
rm: /usr/local/include/node/common.gypi: Permission denied
```

How do I fix the problem with the installation?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I assume that you are using Mac.
try

```
sudo rm: /usr/local/include/node/common.gypi
```

Also add node PATH to your environment variables.

Comment: Yes, it's mac. After running the sudo rm: /usr/local/include/node/common.gypi   , I am getting the error " sudo: rm:: command not found"

Comment: Ok, so you already have an existing version of Node. But you are trying to install the latest version. So try the following. 1. brew update 2. brew upgrade node

Comment: I have been trying to install but keep getting the error " Warning: The post-install step did not complete successfully
You can try again using `brew postinstall node`"  The error continues "brew postinstall node
==> Postinstalling node
Warning: The post-install step did not complete successfully
You can try again using `brew postinstall node`" Have been trying to look for options online which asks for reinstalls but just not able to fix it.

Comment: I just installed brew this morning so that is up to date